# Can't load socket.io using node.js: io is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I generated an express app by using express-generator and when including socket.io I've noticed that socket.io client is not being loading by the browser. I've been 2 days searching on the internet for a solution with no success.

I followed socket.io instructions for express 3/4 and in fact the socket.io client that is exposed by the server on /socket.io/socket.io.js is being served (no 404 errors).
**The problem is that when javascript code that tries to use socket io client fails because "io is not defined"**

**Any ideas about why the browser is not loading the client although it states that HTTP GET to http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js returns HTTP 200?**

By the way, the app is also using Angular.js.

index.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
</script>
```

app.js (no error logs and socket.io server debug message says " socket.io:server serve client source +3s")

```
// setup server
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

console.log(app.get('port'));

server.listen(app.get('port'),  function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);

});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**Update:**

By using socket.io CDN the result is the same. It does not work

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have the right server-side version of socket.io installed server-side?  Did you look at what `http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js` gives you from the client?  Is the file what you expect?  Is `io` defined in it?  Are there any other errors in the client?  Do you need to clear your browser cache?

Comment: @jfriend00 socket.io version is 1.4.6. Regarding the file I'm getting from the client is this: https://gist.github.com/endymion00/a69c9f187c1dc9c3e8f05443f5cd0c57 . As I said the only error in the client is " Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined" and I also tried to clear browser cache several times as well trying it using anonymous browsing.

Comment: I can confirm that that file does not contain a definition of `io` so it's clearly not the right file or not the complete file.  Something must be messed up with your server-side installation of socket.io.  What did you do when installing socket.io on the server?  Did you copy any files around manually after installing?

Comment: @jfriend00 quite strange, in fact the only thing I did when installing was the required "npm install socket.io --save". I also tested the socket.io example chat application and it works. The only difference between my app and chat example is that my app has more app.set/app.use calls and that is was generated using express-generator. I tried to alter the order of app."x" calls but with not success yet (and obviously I checked socket.io "get started").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.
I finally found a solution for this problem but I still don't know what was the cause.

The solution was to move `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` before any other  tags (there are 16 script declarations: angular, bootstrap, jquery, moment, etc.).

**So if you get "Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined" message on the browser move first "" at the beginning of the page inside  tags**. It will save you a lot of effort trying to make it work.

Comment: i dont understand .. what exactly is the solution ???

Comment: @dll_onFire solution is that socket.io reference on your html file must be placed before other libraries.

Comment: @testing_22 great, I'm glad this helped someone after more than 5 years! :)